# SpringBoot: cannot access @Controller method

Tags: spring-boot

I have initialized Spring Boot 3.2.2 application.
I have few modules like dao, model, config (here I have main class), service (in this module there's my controller)

my main class:

```
package notifications;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.config.EnableR2dbcRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableR2dbcRepositories

public class NotificationsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NawaNotificationsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and my controller class:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;


import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


import java.util.*;

@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class NotificationController {

    private final NotificationService notificationService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/hello", produces = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> hello() {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Your response...", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Problem is that i cannot access my api/hello method after application start.
I tried localhost:8080/api/hello, localhost:8080/notifications/api/hello, but it gives me 404 from tomcat.

If I move controller class next to spring boot main class it works for me, I have response from http://localhost:8080/api/hello

I tried with component scan but with no effect, maybe wrong expression with this annotation

My project structure with main and controller class visible:

[image]

Comment: it doesnt works, that's not the problem, i write in post 'If I move controller class next to spring boot main class it works for me, I have response from http://localhost:8080/api/hello'

Comment: Your java classes should live in a subpackage of `notifications` not in the default package. see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html for best practace

Comment: I add notifications package above all java files, but still doesnt work. Controller located next to main class work properly

Comment: Seems that you don't have one application but multiple modules instead. If this is really what you want you'll have to configure the application by hand. But I think more that you have misstaken `module` for `package`. Try to restructure your project so that in the end you have only one module (the blue box one) at root level and all the other packages inside it. So `notifications` is the one that shall remain.

Answer (score 0):

I can see `package notifications;` in your `NotificationsApplication` but i can not see the same package in the `NotificationController`. please consider about it first.

Comment: I add notifications package above all java files, but still doesnt work. Controller located next to main class work properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure all the files for an application are residing in a single module. If you want whole src/main seperation, then you need to configure it manually, it will become a **mono-repo**.

I suggest don't make separate **modules**, put things in separate **directories** inside one module and outside those directories should reside the NawaNotificationsApplication or the main class for SpringBootApplication.